# Is there a USB interface for a RadioShack 22-812 Digital multimeter?

Tags: usb, serial, multimeter

I have a RadioShack 22-812 Digital Multimeter which has a Serial PC Interface.

Is there any sort of adapter that I can use to connect it to a computer's USB port instead of using the Serial Port?

Comment: Always be aware that when using non-isolated equipment, unexpected things may happen; especially ground loops which can at best be annoying and at worst cause extreme damage and fire.

Comment: The interface *is* isolated.  It uses an IR LED / phototransistor pair.  The LED is powered by the meter's battery and the phototransistor is powered by the RS232 line.  Communication is one-way.  And the LED current will kill the battery after a few days of continuous use.  But it makes a handy data logger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RS232 to USB is very common. Here is an example:

[http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-RS232-Serial-Adapter-ICUSB232/dp/tags-on-product/B000067SNB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067SNB)

Expanding a little, these cables will create a virtual com port on your computer. So when you plug it in, even if there isn't anything connected to the cable, drivers will be installed and a virtual com port will be generated. Because of how it does this it looks like you just plugged the serial cable into the computer directly.

Comment: I have used a Prolific cable (like the one linked) with the 22-812 meter.  And it worked fine.  I wrote my own Python script, available on request.  There are lots of scripts and software out there if you Google "22-812".

Comment: Here is the exact adapter I used:  http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-to-rs232-db9-serial-port-adapter-22407  Notice that it uses a real charge pump IC to make the RS232 voltages.  This is good, because the 22-812 needs the proper voltage to power the phototransistor inside.